# How can I handle tp_print in C code with Python 3.8 on Mac?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I need to build C++ code compatible with the Python C API for Python 3.7 and 3.8 on Mac, Windows, and Linux. The problem is that on Mac, for 3.8.1, the clang compiler gives me grief about a `PyTypeObject` definition whether I initialize a `tp_print` field at the end (resulting message: `tp_print is deprecated [-Werror, -Wdeprecated-declarations`) or omit it (resulting message: `missing field 'tp-print' initializer [-Werror,-Wmissing-field-initializers]`). By contrast, Visual C++ on Windows accepts the code either way. Meanwhile, although g++ on Linux complains, like clang, when I fail to initialize the `tp_print` field, it is at least satisfied when I do initialize it.

The tail of the `PyTypeObject` code that I'm initializing looks like this when I do initialize `tp_print`:

```
    0,                            // tp_weaklist
    0,                            // tp_del
    0,                            // tp_version_tag
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    0                             // tp_finalize
#endif
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 3 && PY_MINOR_VERSION >= 8
    ,
    0                             // tp_vectorcall
    ,
    0                             // tp_print
#endif
};
```

When I don't initialize `tp_print`, it looks like this:

```
    0,                            // tp_weaklist
    0,                            // tp_del
    0,                            // tp_version_tag
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    0                             // tp_finalize
#endif
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 3 && PY_MINOR_VERSION >= 8
    ,
    0                             // tp_vectorcall
    //,
    //0                             // tp_print
#endif
};
```

I find that if I include this code before the definition:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#endif
```

and this code afterwards:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```

then everything works. Is there a more elegant way to solve this issue? What do the Python developers want us to do: initialize `tp_print`, or not?

Comment: `tp_print` doesn't exist any more. It got replaced by `tp_vectorcall_offset`.

Comment: ...well, the docs say that, but apparently the actual struct definition in the header looks different.

Comment: I think your best option is to turn off Wmissing-field-initializers. The Python C API isn't designed with that warning in mind.

Comment: If I turned off Wmissing-field-initializers for clang, I'd need to turn off the similar message for g++. I don't mind doing that, but I'm just mentioning it.